# mongodb v3.2 can't run in mac

Tags: mongodb, macos

I have a mac running El Capitan 10.11 with node.js v6.9.1.
I am trying to install mongodb 3.2 with homebrew.  It seems to install but when I run mongod I get this error:

```
Found an invalid index { v: 2, key: { version: 1 }, name:
"incompatible_with_version_32",ns: "admin.system.version" } on the
admin.system.version collection: this version of mongod cannot 
build new indexes of version number 2
```

I thought it might be because I had another version of mongodb before, so I uninstalled all packages previously downloaded and verified with 'brew list'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this version of mongod cannot build new indexes of version number 2

It looks like you previously installed MongoDB 3.4 and created some data files using new features which are [not backward compatible](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/#backwards-incompatible-features) with MongoDB 3.2. MongoDB 3.4 introduced `v:2` indexes which support [language-specific collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/).

> I thought it might be because I had another version of mongodb before, so I uninstalled all packages previously downloaded and verified with 'brew list'.

Uninstalling a Homebrew package generally does not remove files that weren't specified in the package formula (or directories that were specified but now have additional files). This intentionally leaves your MongoDB `dbPath` intact so package updates do not affect your data.

> Any idea what Im doing wrong here?

There are several approaches you can take to resolve this issue:

- Install a MongoDB 3.4 server instead of 3.2.
- Follow the documented steps to [downgrade MongoDB 3.4 to 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-downgrade/). This will require using MongoDB 3.4 to remove incompatible features from your data files.
- If the previous data in your `dbPath` is not important (e.g. development/test data that can be recreated), move all files in your `dbPath` to a new location so your 3.2 server starts with an empty data directory. The default `dbPath` for Homebrew (assuming you are starting/stopping MongoDB as a service) will be `/usr/local/var/mongodb`.