# Mongodb Enterprise (encrypted) Found an invalid index

Tags: mongodb, encryption, enterprise

Maybe someone has an idea. With one of our mongo dbs we keep getting the following:

*Found an invalid index { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "KEYDB.keys" } on the KEYDB.keys collection: this version of mongod cannot build new indexes   of version number 2*

It mentions: db version v3.2.19
We tried to access it on Mongo Enterprise versions: 3.2.19 or 3.4 or latest 3.6 but no cigar.

Any ideas how to fix this pickle?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do when you get this error message?

Comment: a couple of days ago i did a server update and i guess mongo got bumped up to a newer version. After that the mongo server doesnt want to start up. I know now that the server was running mongo enterprise 3.4.10. and i only tried it with 3.4.19 maybe if i try with x.x.10 it'll work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb v3.2 can't run in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163776/mongodb-v3-2-cant-run-in-mac)